# PHP: Codeigniter get upcoming birthdays within two dates

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, date

I have an employees table like this

```
id   name   dob
1    Vik    1990-01-12
2    Arm    1992-02-08
3    Loki   1992-02-19
4    Ram    1986-11-23
5    Suri   1996-03-02
```

Today is 2015-02-05,  Now I want those records whom birthday between 2015-02-01 to 2015-02-28. Means output will be

```
2    Arm    1992-02-08
3    Loki   1992-02-19
```

I am familiar only with Codeigniter, so my request is please write your answer according to CI query.

Comment: What's your code so far?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM `employees` WHERE MONTH(dob) = 2 AND (DAY(dob) >= 1 AND DAY(dob) < 29);
```

[Test](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f5261/1).

Comment: I tried it in sql and it is working but how I'll use it in CI

Comment: its working for single month. if we want date from two months how will execute this code?

Comment: @mathew You could probably try something like `$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM employees WHERE MONTH(dob) = $monthVarFirst OR MONTH(dob) = $monthVarSecond;")`.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably better to pull the information straight from the database so you don't require grabbing all records and doing a loop.

Another alternative to @Tpojka example is to use the BETWEEN function if using MySQL:

```
SELECT * FROM `employees` WHERE dob BETWEEN $start_date AND $end_date;
```

To use it in CodeIgniter, you need to have a database config setup, before you can do something like this:

```
$this->db->query('SELECT * FROM `employees` WHERE dob BETWEEN ? AND ?;', array($start_date, $end_date));
```